# Alarm Settings on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: settings, alarm, clock

Since updating to Jelly Bean, I can no longer change the settings of my alarms on my S3 i.e snooze (time in between, length), activate smart alarm, change the alarm tone etc... When I click more, it just lets me change the volume. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you give us a screenshot of what "more" you're referring to?  I do not see any such thing to click on on my GS3 and you just scroll down to see the options you're referring to.

Comment: Are you still using the "Clock" app? I have JB too, I use Clock to set alarms and I can set all of these options.

Answer (score 1):

After you tap "more" you can scroll down to change more than just the volume. I didn't think there was anything else, either, at first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but since you updated to JB, It may have other stock alarm app, so it wouldn't be some bug. Although you can download an app for this, like [Xtreme Alarm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alarmclock.xtreme.free&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hbGFybWNsb2NrLnh0cmVtZS5mcmVlIl0.) which is free.

Or you can search on XDA forums the stock alarm APK for ICS. I've found [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1969991) topic, which lists a lot of stock apps for downloading.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't figured it out yet, (or for future reference):

From the clock app, tap on the alarm in question. You'll be brought to the original settings you saw when you first set it. Tap on `more` at the bottom.